# Laravel Replace existing DB value - Favourites

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to setup a favourites button on an article. The following code works ...

```
public function favouriteNotfavouriteArticleParent(Request $request){

    $data = [];
    $data['user_id'] = Auth::id();
    $data['person_id'] = GetPersonData()['id'];
    $data['article_id'] = $request->get('article_id');
    $data['action'] = $request->get('action');
    UserFavourites::updateOrCreate($data,$data);

}
```

However, i want it to firstly check for any existing values set for that article ID. If it has favourite set and notfavourite is clicked, it should remove the favourite table row.

At the minute it just adds a row for favourite and notfavourite. I've attached a screenshot of the current sql behaviour.

Any help is massively appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hi I just want to alter the favourites column from fav to non fav by cross referencing the article I’d column

Comment: I'm assuming that you also want it to be unique to the `user_id` as well?

Comment: Yes sorry that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdateOrCreate` takes two arguments. The first argument is an array of attributes to look for and the second argument is an array of attributes to change. If there isn't a row in the database that has attributes from the first array the arrays will essentially be combined to make a new row in the database.

To achieve what you're after you could do the following:

```
UserFavourites::updateOrCreate([
    'article_id' => $request->input('article_id'),
    'user_id'    => auth()->id(),
], [
    'person_id' => GetPersonData()['id'],
    'action'    => $request->input('action'),
]);
```

The above will look for a row that matches the `article_id` and `user_id` and then either update the `person_id` and `action` for that row or (if the row doesn't exist) create a new row with all the attributes.

Comment: This works, however it still creates duplicates rather than removing previous ones

Comment: There should only be one row for each user and article - favourite or notfavourite.